# How to play dailymotion live stream in one time?

Tags: android, android-webview, live-streaming

I'm developing an android application and I should create a live stream shower activity. But there is a problem that I cannot solve. Problem is:
When I open the activity. This screen comes:
[image]

When I click the play button. This comes:(Problem is this screen. Fourth screen shold be come.) I have to press left-bottom corner of screen(stop button) 
[image]

... and press the same corner again(play button)
[image]

After this actions live stream comes..
[image]

What can I do to solve this problem? Codes are:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zindi);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    final String rsp = convertStreamToString(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ceribin2));
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://zaroktv.com.tr/", rsp, null, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("LINE" + (++i), line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

ceribin2.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>ZarokTV</title>
</head>
<body >
<div class='embed-container'><iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x327os6" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</body>
```